Xamarin Form Android Unable to instantiate activity
I am able to run my applications, but I have Addition Settings in the app set with this:
<activity android:label="Settings" android:name=".SettingsActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

And here is my settingsActivity:
namespace Registrations.Droid
{
    public class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SupportFragmentManager
            .BeginTransaction()
            .Replace(Android.Resource.Id.Content, new SettingsFragment())
            .Commit();
        }
    }
    public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat
    {
        public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
        {
            SetPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
}

And I get this error

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.jamessuske.registrations/com.jamessuske.registrations.SettingsActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.jamessuske.registrations.SettingsActivity" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/lib/x86,
/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
/system/lib]] ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.jamessuske.registrations.SettingsActivity" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/lib/x86,
/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
/system/lib]]   at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.jamessuske.registrations.SettingsActivity" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/lib/x86,
/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
/system/lib]]   at at
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)   at at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)   at at
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
at at
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
at at
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
at at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
at at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at at
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)   at at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)   at at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)   at at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.jamessuske.registrations/com.jamessuske.registrations.SettingsActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.jamessuske.registrations.SettingsActivity" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/lib/x86,
/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
/system/lib]]   at at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
at at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at at
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at at
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)   at at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)   at at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)   at at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"com.jamessuske.registrations.SettingsActivity" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/lib/x86,
/data/app/com.jamessuske.registrations-SFThqa3YjC3Gvuv4Cf-ygQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
/system/lib]]   at at
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)   at at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)   at at
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
at at
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
at at
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
at at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
at ... 11 more

I tried to do the following:
[Activity(Name = "Registrations.Mobile.Droid.SettingsActivity", Label = "Settings")]
public class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

Based off this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934825/979331 but it did not work.
What am I doing wrong?


Is there MainActivity exsiting in your project? If so, could please add it to your post? 2. Have you try to set MainLauncher = true  in SettingsActivity? 3. Is it a Xamarin forms project? If so, you should define activity like


`public class Activity1 : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}`

